# Help solving an important ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I could use some help solving the ODE 
$$(1+x^{2})y''+4xy'+2y=0$$

I have entered it into wolfram and it gave me the partial details of a solution. It read to rewrite $2=(4x)'-(x^{2}+1)''$ into the ODE.I gather we are to "reverse" the product rule. If would be helpful if someone can provide the remaining detail.Better yet if someone knows a better technique to approach to solve the ODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint
$$(1+x^{2})y''+4xy'+2y=0$$
$$y''+(x^{2}y''+2xy')+2(xy'+y)=0$$
$$y''+(x^{2}y')'+2(xy)'=0$$
Integrate 
$$y'+(x^2y')+2xy=K$$
$$y'(1+x^2)+2xy=K$$
$$y'+(x^2y)'=K$$
integrate again
$$y+(x^2y)=K_1x+K_2$$
$$y(1+x^2)=K_1x+K_2$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=\frac {K_1x+K_2}{(1+x^2)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $v = 1+x^2$, the DE says $$ v y'' + 2 v' y' + v'' y = 0$$

Note that the left side is $(v y)''$.

The fact that this all works out so neatly should not lead to overconfidence: most second-order DE's with non-constant coefficients have non-elementary solution.  For example, if you changed the last term from $2y$ to $y$ the solutions would not be elementary (they could be written in terms of hypergeometric functions).